How can I round a number in Kotlin-multiplatform without using external libraries?
I have a KMP project, and I want to round the doubles into the needed number of decimals, without implementing this in each platform, using primitive types and standard library is preferable.

You can create an extension function and use strings with functional methods like this:
import kotlin.math.pow

fun Double.roundTo(dec: Int): Double {
    return toString().split('.').let {
        if (it.last().length <= dec) this
        else {
            val decimals = it.last().drop(it.last().length - dec)
            (it.first() + decimals).toDouble() / 10.0.pow(dec)
        }
    }
}

Thanks for the feedback in the comments, I found a better way:
import kotlin.math.pow
import kotlin.math.round

fun Double.roundTo(dec: Int): Double {
    return round(this * 10.0.pow(dec)) / 10.0.pow(dec)
}


The docs for Double.toString() say: “Note that the representation format is unstable and may change in a future release.”  So this approach may be a little fragile…  (It's also inefficient — though that's less important than correctness and platform-independence.)

Using your code, 1.23456.roundTo(2) returns 1.56 - not what you want. Also, note that it is impossible generally to get a Double to be exactly a number to a certain number of decimal places. Floating-point types, i.e. Float and Double, store their values in binary and therefore it is not possible to represent exact decimal values. For example, look at what 1.23 actually is: BigDecimal(1.23) returns 1.229999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875. So your attempt to round a number is only approximate.

thank you for your quick comments, I found another way that gives me the right answer!
